# Job in rails is being executed :inline despite setting queue_adapter to :sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I was exploring different tutorials on how to set-up and use sidekiq to execute process in the background. I decided to follow [this tutorial](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/sidekiq-basics#show_notes) and follow everything exactly. However, when I start trying to execute the job, nothing is being added in my sidekiq queue and the job executes inline.

Like in the tutorial, I was expecting that every time I try to execute the job, it should reflect in my sidekiq however when I do that, it stays like this:

[image]

while my rails server executes the job itself
[image]

Here are the codes in the necessary files needed as shown in the tutorial:

My Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile.rb

source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.0'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'semantic-ui-sass', github: 'doabit/semantic-ui-sass'
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'chartkick'
gem 'groupdate'
gem 'faker', :git => 'https://github.com/stympy/faker.git', :branch => 'master'

gem 'rest-client'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.6', '>= 4.6.1'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

My job:

```
#generate_random_vehicle_job.rb

class GenerateRandomVehicleJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    detected_vehicle = DetectedVehicle.new
    detected_vehicle.detection_time = Faker::Date.between(30.days.ago, Date.today)
    detected_vehicle.license_plate_text = Faker::Vehicle.license_plate
    detected_vehicle.camera_id = rand(1..Camera.count)
    #detected_vehicle = DetectedVehicle.create(detection_time: date, camera_id: camera_id, license_plate_text: license_plate)
    detected_vehicle.license_plate_image.attach(io: File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'sample_plate.png')), filename: 'sample_plate.png', content_type: 'image/png')
    detected_vehicle.vehicle_image.attach(io: File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'sample_vehicle.jpg')), filename: 'sample_vehicle.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpeg')
    detected_vehicle.video_footage_snippet.attach(io: File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'sample_video.mp4')), filename: 'sample_video.mp4', content_type: 'video/mp4')
    sleep 2
  end
end
```

My application.rb:

```
# config/application.rb
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module CatchAllApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.2
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq 

    # No need to run sidekiq and redis server in development
    #config.active_job.queue_adapter = Rails.env.production? ? :sidekiq : :async

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.
  end
end
```

My sidekiq.rb

```
# config/initializers/sidekiq.rb

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0' }
end
```

And finally, my controller:

```
  def create_random_vehicle
    GenerateRandomVehicleJob.perform_later
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

I am sure that my redis-server, rails server, and sidekiq are all up and running properly.

Comment: Have you checked that your config/environment/development.rb doesn't override the `active_job.queue_adapter`?

Comment: That was exactly the problem! Thanks! :) On a side note, while I was trying to explore for solutions earlier, I tried to set up a sidekiq:worker via `rails generate sidekiq:worker random_vehicle_generator`. I just used the same code for the perform and when I tried it, the jobs get queued properly. I am just quite curious why that worked despite having the overridden queue_adapter in my `development.rb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that my `active_job.queue_adapter` has been overridden by my `config/environment/development.rb` as pointed out above by @max pleaner. I just removed the `active_job.queue_adapter = :inline` and it fixed my problem! :)